# Removing duplicates - Need to match on business name and multiple addresses

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I need to identify and remove duplicates based on 'businessName' AND a complete matching address. Given the XML below I would expect that client's with id of 1 and 3 match because the businessName matches AND at least one of their addresses match (address1, city, state postalCode...address2 not included).  Note that for the address match the 'postalCode' need only match the first 5 digits...NOT the +4 zip.

XSLT 2.0 OK (Saxon Enterprise Edition)

I would assume I would use a for-each-group but I'm confused on how to deal with the address match when there can be multiple addresses per client.  I've been playing with following-sibling but not getting anywhere. Any solutions or pointers appreciated.  Thanks.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Clients/client" group-by="businessName">
</xsl:for-each-group>


<Clients>
    <client>
        <id>1</id>
        <businessName>ABC Tile</businessName>
        <addresses>
            <address>
                <address1>PO Box 1057</address1>
                <address2/>
                <city>Denver</city>
                <state>CO</state>
                <postalCode>801230000</postalCode>
            </address>
            <address>
                <address1>PO Box 621188</address1>
                <address2/>
                <city>Denver</city>
                <state>CO</state>
                <postalCode>801230000</postalCode>
            </address>
        </addresses>
    </client>
    <client>
        <id>2</id>
        <businessName>123 Tile</businessName>
        <addresses>
            <address>
                <address1>567 Main Street</address1>
                <address2/>
                <city>Denver</city>
                <state>CO</state>
                <postalCode>801230000</postalCode>
            </address>
        </addresses>
    </client>
    <client>
        <id>3</id>
        <businessName>ABC Tile</businessName>
        <addresses>
            <address>
                <address1>123 Main Street</address1>
                <address2/>
                <city>Denver</city>
                <state>CO</state>
                <postalCode>801230000</postalCode>
            </address>
            <address>
                <address1>PO Box 1057</address1>
                <address2/>
                <city>Denver</city>
                <state>CO</state>
                <postalCode>801235555</postalCode>
            </address>
        </addresses>
    </client>
</Clients>
```

This is the desired result where client id 1 lists all client id matches.

```
<Clients>
    <client>
        <id>1</id>
        <clientMatch>3</clientMatch>
        <businessName>ABC Tile</businessName>
        <addresses>
            <address>
                <address1>PO Box 1057</address1>
                <address2/>
                <city>Denver</city>
                <state>CO</state>
                <postalCode>801230000</postalCode>
            </address>
            <address>
                <address1>PO Box 621188</address1>
                <address2/>
                <city>Denver</city>
                <state>CO</state>
                <postalCode>801230000</postalCode>
            </address>
        </addresses>
    </client>
    <client>
        <id>2</id>
        <businessName>123 Tile</businessName>
        <addresses>
            <address>
                <address1>567 Main Street</address1>
                <address2/>
                <city>Denver</city>
                <state>CO</state>
                <postalCode>801230000</postalCode>
            </address>
        </addresses>
    </client>
</Clients>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `for-each-group` on the `businessName` but further use of that construct is difficult as you want to compare whether at least one `address` of multiple ones matches. So I came up with http://xsltransform.net/gWvjQeP/1 which does

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:function name="mf:key" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="address" as="element(address)"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="concat($address/address1, '|', $address/city, '|', $address/state, '|', substring($address/postalCode, 1, 5))"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="Clients">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="client" group-by="businessName">
          <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
              <xsl:variable name="pos" as="xs:integer" select="position()"/>
              <xsl:if test="not(current-group()[position() lt $pos][addresses/address/mf:key(.) = current()/addresses/address/mf:key(.)])">
                  <xsl:copy>
                      <xsl:copy-of select="id"/>
                      <clientMatch>
                          <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[position() gt $pos][addresses/address/mf:key(.) = current()/addresses/address/mf:key(.)]/id" separator=", "/>
                      </clientMatch>
                      <xsl:copy-of select="* except id"/>
                  </xsl:copy>
              </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

I am not sure whether you want to output all `address` elements of all matching elements or only those of the first one, your question only shows the ones of the first one so currently the sample does that.

Comment: I think that gets me where I need to be.  Thank you for the detailed answer and example. Always learning.